# My anchor point in my HTML isn't taking me to the right position on the page

Tags: css, html, structure

Live example - http://sofactor.com/ when you click on "Services" it will take you to the bottom of the page. The rest of my anchors are set up the same and work, but my Services anchor doesn't... Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because of the download link, which shares the same name in the ID

Answer (score 0):

Your page is functionally correct. Your button is what your download link is directing to

```
<div id="services" <a href="#" class="button">Download</div>
```

Just simply remove the `id="services"` and put it on your h3 where I believe you want it to be